# Unwanted Highlighting Issue in Android RecyclerView Item Selection and Swapping an Item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a feature where, when an item is selected in a RecyclerView, it gets highlighted with a specific color "int color = Color.parseColor("#B6C4B6");" and some animation.

When the user selects the first item, it gets highlighted correctly using `int color = Color.parseColor("#B6C4B6")`.

However, after selecting the second item and swapping them, other items also get highlighted unexpectedly just like `int color = Color.parseColor("#B6C4B6")`

**In the activity class:**

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(WordEnglish wordEnglish, int position) {
        if (swappedItems.contains(wordEnglish)) {
            // Item has already been swapped, do nothing or show a message
            return;
        }

        if (selectedPosition == -1)
        {
            // First item selected, save its position and highlight it
            selectedPosition = position;
            View selectedItemView = englishword_recycler_view.getChildAt(position);
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = selectedItemView.findViewById(R.id.RL);

            // Replace "#FFFF00" with your desired hex color code
            int color = Color.parseColor("#B6C4B6");

            // Create an ObjectAnimator to change the background color
            ObjectAnimator backgroundColorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
                    relativeLayout,
                    "backgroundColor",
                    color
            );

            // Set the animator duration
            backgroundColorAnimator.setDuration(1000); // Set your desired duration in milliseconds

            // Apply the color change
            backgroundColorAnimator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
            backgroundColorAnimator.start();

            // Define animation duration (in milliseconds)
            backgroundColorAnimator.setDuration(300); // Adjust duration as needed

            // Create a scale animation for pop-up effect
            ObjectAnimator scaleXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    relativeLayout,
                    View.SCALE_X,
                    2.0f,
                    1.2f,
                    1.0f
            );

            ObjectAnimator scaleYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    relativeLayout,
                    View.SCALE_Y,
                    2.0f,
                    1.2f,
                    1.0f
            );

            // Create an alpha animation for fading effect
            ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    relativeLayout,
                    View.ALPHA,
                    1.0f,
                    0.7f,
                    1.0f
            );

            // Define animation duration and interpolator
            int animationDuration = 300; // Adjust duration as needed
            scaleXAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
            scaleYAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
            alphaAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);

            // Set an interpolator for smooth acceleration and deceleration
            AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
            scaleXAnimator.setInterpolator(interpolator);
            scaleYAnimator.setInterpolator(interpolator);
            alphaAnimator.setInterpolator(interpolator);

            // Create an AnimatorSet to play all animations together
            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
            animatorSet.playTogether(backgroundColorAnimator, scaleXAnimator, scaleYAnimator, alphaAnimator);
            animatorSet.start();


        }
        else
        {
            // Second item selected, swap positions
            int targetPosition = position;
            swapItems(selectedPosition, targetPosition);

            // Mark the items as swapped
            //swappedItems.add(wordEnglish);
            swappedItems.add(wordEnglishList.get(targetPosition));

            //showSwappedItemsToast();

            selectedPosition = -1; // Reset selected position
            adapterEnglishWord.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify the adapter

            adapterEnglishWord.setReviewMode(true);
            adapterEnglishWord.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // Convert Set to List
            List<WordEnglish> swappedItemsList = new ArrayList<>(swappedItems);
            adapterEnglishWord.setSwappedItems(swappedItemsList);
        }
    }
```

**The adapter's onBindViewHolder:**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MatchEnglishWordAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        WordEnglish wordEnglish = wordEnglishList.get(position);
        WordHindiTranslation correctAnswer = correctAnswerList.get(position);

        holder.wordTextView.setText(wordEnglish.getENGLISH());

        if (isReviewMode)
        {
            if (swappedItems.contains(wordEnglish))
            {
                if (wordEnglish.getENGLISH().equals(correctAnswer.getENGLISH()))
                {
                    holder.RL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_correct_item_background);
                    holder.wordTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                else
                {
                    holder.RL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_match_answer);
                    holder.wordTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
            else if (!swappedItems.contains(wordEnglish))
            {
                holder.RL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.swapped_item); // Reset to the default background
                holder.wordTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                //Toast.makeText(holder.RL.getContext(), "else if", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (!isReviewMode)
        {
            holder.RL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.swapped_item);// Load this at the initial launch
            holder.wordTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Two things stand out that you should review. 1. Do not access views directly through the recyclerview: (`View selectedItemView = englishword_recycler_view.getChildAt(position);`) - they are getting recycled / swapped around as the user scrolls. And 2 - do not do logic in your `onBind...` method - it should do one thing - slap the current view state onto the view at that position. In short: onClick should delegate to some ViewModel or other object that does the logic of figuring out what is the current state of all the items and onBind just sets those states.